# Custom Java Events

Tags: java, events, event-handling

How do I do the following:

I need to know how to create a certain type of event.

Have a class called Stater, and have a class called Event.
The class starter would just initialize all of the listeners, so all I would need to do from another class is just :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Starter starter = new Starter();
        starter.start();
    }
}
```

The start() method just fires the event called Event. However, I don't want any code to be preset when the event fires, so that I can do:

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Starter starter = new Starter();
            starter.start();
        }
        public void onEvent(Event event) {
            /* 
            Code when Event fires
            For example, System.out.println(event.getName());
             */
        }
    }
```

The onEvent method could be called anything. All it does is just run when Event is fired.

I want to know how to be able to create an event like this. I've been trying to find how to do this for weeks, but I couldn't. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want any code to be preset"?

Comment: When you say "just fires the event called Event" - what does this code actually do, can you show how you are triggering the event? What technology are you using or planning to use to implement this, are the events some kind of message in a queue, is this JMS or Kafka, or are we talking about UI events?

Comment: @HenryTwist I mean that the person writing Main has to specify what the event does when it is fired using "public void onEvent(Event event) {}"

Comment: @KevinHooke I'm trying to figure out how to trigger the event. That's what I'm asking. And as for what the event is, it's just a generic event that doesn't do anything until the person writing Main specifies what it does with "public void onEvent(Event event) {}" and that can be fired with a method in any class.

Answer (score 0):

you should use what `callbacks`. In Java, it is usually used with lambdas allowing short and highly readable code.
let's create a class `Starter`.

```
public class Starter {

   private Consumer<Object> onStart;

   public void setOnStart(Consumer<Object> onStart) {
      this.onStart=onStart;
   }

   public void start() {
      // any code
      if(this.onStart != null) 
         this.onStart(<any params>);
    
   }

}
```

now you can run it:

```java
// ...

public static void main(String...args) [
   Starter starter = new Starter();
   starter.setOnStart((obj) -> System.out.println("started starter"));
   

   starter.start();
   // prints started starter
   // calls the callback

}

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the observer pattern and pub sub pattern

Observer

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm

Publish–subscribe pattern

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern
- https://riptutorial.com/design-patterns/example/6498/publish-subscribe-in-java

Observer pattern vs pub sub pattern

- https://hackernoon.com/observer-vs-pub-sub-pattern-50d3b27f838c